# Getting return type invalid error while trying to call WCF webservice 4.0

Tags: wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I am trying to write and call WCF web service, below are the details:

**Web.config:**

```
<add relativeAddress="FetchData.svc" service="WCF.Services.FetchData" />

<service name="WCF.Services.FetchData">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="FetchData" contract="WCF.Services.FetchData" />
</service>
```

**FetchData Class (Sample Code):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using Webservices.Services;
using Data = Webservices.Data;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text;


namespace WCF.Services
{    
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:WCF.Services.FetchData")]
    public class FetchData
    {
        Data.GetConnect mConnect = new Data.GetConnect();
        private Message RetrievePublishedData(String pub, int number)
        {
            String strOutput = String.Empty; 
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pub))
            {
                Boolean pubURLExists = mConnect.CheckPubUrlExists(pub);

                if (!pubURLExists)
                {
                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(String.Format("Requested publication '{0}' is not available.", pub), MimeTypes.TextPlain, Encoding.UTF8);
                }
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriterEncoding())
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        hw.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
                        XmlNode publishedData = mConnect.GetPublishedData(pub, number);
                        hw.RenderEndTag();
                    }
                    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(sw.ToString(),MimeTypes.TextHTML, Encoding.UTF8);
                }
            }
            return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(strOutput, MimeTypes.TextHTML, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/published/{number}/{*pub=default}")]
        public Message FetchPublished(String pub, int number)
        {
           return RetrievePublishedData(pub, number);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to browse the web service, I am getting below error:

Web Service URL - `http://localhost:8082/FetchData.svc`

**Error:**
*The operation 'FetchPublished' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.*

**Edit:**

```
namespace WCFWebServices
{
    [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
     [ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:WCFWebServices.fetchPush")]
        public class FetchData
        {
         [MessageContract]
         public class RetrievePublishedDataInput
         {
             [MessageBodyMember]
             public String pub;
             [MessageBodyMember]
             public String number;
         }
            private Message RetrievePublishedData(RetrievePublishedDataInput input)
            {
                String strOutput = String.Empty;
                String pub = input.pub;
                String number = input.number;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pub))
                {
                    Boolean pubURLExists = true;

                    if (!pubURLExists)
                    {
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(String.Format("Requested publication '{0}' is not available.", pub), "application/plain; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                        {
                            hw.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);

                            hw.RenderEndTag();
                        }
                        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(sw.ToString(), "application/html; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                }
                return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(strOutput, "application/html; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
            }
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/publishedData/{number}/{pub=default}")]
            public Message FetchPublished(RetrievePublishedDataInput input)
            {
                return RetrievePublishedData(input);
            }
        }      
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe mentioned error is quite self-explaining. According to [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), using `Message` class has its own restrictions:

> You can use the Message class as an input parameter of an operation, the return value of an operation, or both. If Message is used anywhere in an operation, the following restrictions apply:
>
> - The operation cannot have any out or ref parameters.
> - There cannot be more than one input parameter. **If the parameter is present, it must be either Message or a message contract type**.
> - The return type must be either void, Message, or a message contract type.

In case of your contract, the second restriction is violated. The easiest workaround is to create proper [`MessageContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[MessageContract]
public class RetrievePublishedDataInput
{
  [MessageBodyMember] public string Pub;
  [MessageBodyMember] public int Number;
}

private Message RetrievePublishedData(RetrievePublishedDataInput input)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Konrad, So what changes I need to do in above code to get it working, whether I am missing some code or doing something wrong as my return type is of Message only

Comment: @ManojSingh, I've updated my answer to show what changes you should do.

Comment: Konrad, it worked, however I am now getting "cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree" when I am trying to call this url "http://localhost:52891/FetchData.svc/published/0"

Comment: @ManojSingh, I've started to describe how to consume `MessageContract` with `webHttpBinding` but I though I will ask why you ever want to return `Message`? I supposed you do it intentionally but maybe it is just a mistake? If you will return normal class, you won't need to use `MessageContract` and normal, REST addresses will be applicable.

Comment: Konrad, thanks as per our architecture we have implemented same way, is there any other ways to implement this, any idea about this The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)...seems missing some configuration

Comment: @ManojSingh, why don't you just return string instead of `Message`, which makes additional and unnecessary troubles? For example, use only `private string RetrievePublishedData(String pub, int number)`

Comment: Konrad, any idea why I stared getting below error "Operation 'FetchPublished' in contract 'FetchData' uses UriTemplate parameters, but also uses a MessageContract parameter. MessageContract and UriTemplate parameters are incompatible"..updated code is added above

Comment: I choose to disagree with the answer. One of the WCF samples does exactly this. Check out [Advanced Format Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It works as long as you use `WebServiceHost`

Comment: In my case, returning string was the cause of the problem.