# Arrays in WCF web services using MessageContracts

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have recently started to work with WCF (late to the game I know) and have been 'playing' with MessageContracts.

I have a very simple scenario in that I have one ServiceContract that has 2 OperationContracts; GetProduct and GetProductList. GetProduct takes a ProductRequest and returns a ProductObject. GetProductList takes a ProductListRequest and returns a ProductListObject. Each of these are shown below.

When I create a windows Forms application and consume the web service, I expect the GetProduct to return a type of Product and GetProductList to return a Type of ProductList, which has a single MessageBodyAttribute called Products which is an array of the Product class returned by GetProduct.

However, The GetProduct method now returns a Product1 object, not a Product. If I get a product list, the items in the array are of type Product as expected.

It seems I have inadvertently created 2 classes for Product and would like to know what I can do to fix this so I have only one Product class, not Product and Product1.

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFMessageContractTest
{
    [OperationContract]
    Product GetProduct(ProductRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
    ProductList GetProductList(ProductListRequest request);
}

    public class WCFService : IWCFMessageContractTest
{
    public Product GetProduct(ProductRequest request)
    {
        string Licence = request.LicenceKey;

        return new Product("Product Description");
    }

    public ProductList GetProductList(ProductListRequest request)
    {
        string Licence = request.LicenceKey;

        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product("Product 1"));
        products.Add(new Product("Product 2"));
        products.Add(new Product("Product 3"));

        ProductList productList = new ProductList(products.ToArray<Product>());

        return productList;
    }

}

    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "ProductRequestObject", WrapperNamespace = "http://mytest.org/Product")]
public class ProductRequest
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://mytest.org/Product")]
    public string LicenceKey { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://mytest.org/Product")]
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "ProductObject", WrapperNamespace = "http://mytest.org/Product")]
public class Product
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://mytest.org/Product")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Product() { }

    public Product(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }
}

    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "ProductListRequestObject", WrapperNamespace = "http://mytest.org/ProductList")]
public class ProductListRequest
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://mytest.org/ProductList")]
    public string LicenceKey { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "ProductListObject", WrapperNamespace = "http://mytest.org/ProductList")]
public class ProductList
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://mytest.org/ProductList")]
    public Product[] Products { get; set; }

    public ProductList() { }

    public ProductList(Product[] ProductArray)
    {
        Products = ProductArray;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you just define the contract as public List<Product> GetProductList(ProductListRequest request);  instead of going through the effort of creating the ProductList class, Seems like a lot of extra effort when all you want to return is a list of products.

Comment: I did start down this route, but when I started the service I got the following error...

Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: The operation 'GetProductListTest' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.

Comment: I think it's because of your use of the MessageContract, do you really need it for such a basic service?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762591/getting-return-type-invalid-error-while-trying-to-call-wcf-webservice-4-0

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, I got side tracked. As I said, these are my first steps into WCF and what I had in mind was a much more complicated service where I wanted to send licence information in the header, and to have a custom class passed in the body. When I tried this I got 2 different definitions of my class in my proxy class. I read that link, but I haven't defined the Message (or referenced it anywhere)